# Filter on exception from generator

Tags: python, exception

I would like to iterate over a generator/iterator and pass the value produced to the function.
The function can either return a new value or raise an error.
I then need to return the value or skip on error.

I came up with the following code:

```py
def yield_or_skip(iter_: Iterable, func: Callable, skip_on_errors: Iterable[Type[Exception]]) -> Iterator:
    skip_on_errors = set(skip_on_errors)
    for item in iter_:
        try:
            yield func(item)
        except Exception as e:
            if type(e) in skip_on_errors:
                continue
            raise
```

It seems to work, but I was wondering if there is a better way to do this?

Note: it has to be an iterator/generator, I can't gather results in a list.

Comment: This is how you'd do it - do you have reasons for suspecting there may be better ways?

Comment: @PaulM. It seems a bit ugly, was wondering if there is a nicer way to do this with functools or something.

Comment: @PaulM. This is **one** way how to do it.

Comment: @InSync You may want to post as an answer so as not to violate the *"Avoid answering questions in comments"* instruction you were shown.

Comment: @KellyBundy I don't think that is an answer. I didn't even read the question; all I noticed was the `type(...) in ...` pattern in the code.

Comment: @InSync Maybe just don't comment on questions you haven't read then. They're asking for a better way, and you showed what you consider a better way. That's answering.

Comment: How can I answer, if I do not know any fully functional solution? Comments can be used to give minor corrections and suggestions, can they not?

Comment: @InSync Some kinds of suggestions, yes. Not the answering kind, though. They belong into answers.

Comment: @KellyBundy Again, that suggestion is not of answering kind. I think "*a better way*" here means something substantial, like a built-in or a library function. Since changing from `type(...) in ...` to `isintance(..., (..., ...))` doesn't fit that understanding *of mine*, I consider it not to be an answer and do not wish to post one. Have I made myself clear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe [suppress](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.suppress)?

```
from contextlib import suppress

def yield_or_skip(iter_: Iterable, func: Callable, skip_on_errors: Iterable[Type[Exception]]) -> Iterator:
    skipper = suppress(*skip_on_errors)
    for item in iter_:
        with skipper:
            yield func(item)
```

Demo:

```
for y in yield_or_skip([2, 0, 3], lambda x: 1/x, [ZeroDivisionError]):
    print(y)

print()

for y in yield_or_skip([2,0,3], lambda x: 1/x, [ValueError]):
    print(y)
```

Output ([Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=fZFLTsMwEIbF1qeYZVK5osAGRYINdMEesSCKojwm1MKxrbED8VnYdAOn4CSchjimrSpVzMb2PD7_v-bjy3i30Wq7_Rxct7z-OfvuSPfgvBHqBURvNDlYsDnZaOVwdFLUu4IdjCG0lrEWO_ACZVtqKu2rMIlwSGUGD9NR1RI5dINqMrirpIzv0FVqVSKRJnvozB-9wXw9Nmic0KooUljexqrTlDGYIswaJLjZS0gWx7x07us0wSSkB6EgCprTId6F2-w4h2yI2ccsN5joU8YCxgfGscX8ksOKw1XBQVZ93VYwZnBxPnLIn5H0vXgTdnKwDoKKNH5iSCiX-Akab__SV_wU-6mSA56ExiX-7XK3018)):

```
0.5
0.3333333333333333

0.5
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/ATO/code", line 26, in <module>
    for y in yield_or_skip([2,0,3], lambda x: 1/x, [ValueError]):
  File "/ATO/code", line 19, in yield_or_skip
    yield func(item)
  File "/ATO/code", line 26, in <lambda>
    for y in yield_or_skip([2,0,3], lambda x: 1/x, [ValueError]):
ZeroDivisionError: division by zero
```

Answer (score 0):

[more_itertools.map_except](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#more_itertools.map_except) does that job. You can use it instead, or use it to implement yours ([Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=fZKxTgMxDIYlxjyFJZZelYoCC7qBBTqwIwZOpyhtcxCRiyMnh5pnYekCD8XTcGl6PYoqPMX57c_WL398uRhe0W63n11oZjffZ7whbCFEp-0L6NYhBZgydg67_xZJCR0UBUTjB72VTqjNSrnA1qr5lU6azq6CRsshNcmlURymWet_fVEy6KNBSnoL2h7qspIiUByTFFErs4YBPUmdxaEgw2GccdzrpPdst-WOIpCEf9MuQUiU8HDYMuFLuJPG5DxVCbRCESH5sbJ6jE5Vi2FcXRcwu81qQMrDSYWO7F9fsieiN-SYXTCWDInJjeMlqysOcw7XNQcj2-VawqaEy4sNh-pZEd7rd-37HRYJU--9daRtmMQeml__0uf8FPtJmk6dhOaj2d_OcEM_)):

```
from more_itertools import map_except

def yield_or_skip(iter_: Iterable, func: Callable, skip_on_errors: Iterable[Type[Exception]]) -> Iterator:
    return map_except(func, iter_, *skip_on_errors)
```

Or adapt its [source code](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/_modules/more_itertools/more.html#map_except):

```
    for item in iterable:
        try:
            yield function(item)
        except exceptions:
            pass
```